# Show gridLines when the chart is empty(no series) in highstock

Tags: highcharts

I want to have the gridLines when there is no series in my chart.

for example: http://jsfiddle.net/bahar_Agi/aQeJ5/ has no series but the girdLines have gone.

```
 series: []
```

How can I set this feature?Is it possible in highstock 1.3.0?

**Note:**I don't want to have gridLines with a default series.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in case when you have no values for axis, you cannot display gridLines. Only what you can display is title when you set up showEmpty option.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.showEmpty
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.showEmpty

Comment: aha, but it the last version I could see the gridLines...Thanks